How to adjust spacing on \includegraphics?
I am currently trying to insert a table inside a pdf. I finally got it working but would just want to figure out how to remove this excess spacing. Here's a screenshot for your reference. 
Code:
\section{EEG Module}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionof{table}{shows the different iterations done for the whole EEG module until the final design was made. }
    \centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight]{Chapter3/Figs/Raster/eeg_table.pdf}
\end{minipage}

EDIT: I've solved the first problem and I thought things would go smoothly this time but I've encountered another issue and I just couldn't get it this stop doing page breaks. Am I missing something?

Code:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} % Document class

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{caption}  % For captions in minipage
\usepackage{float}    % To control float positioning

% Graphics Path
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{images/}} % Adjust the folder name if needed
\else
    \graphicspath{{images/}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\chapter{System Development and Unit Testing}

\section{EEG Module}
Table 3.1 shows the different iterations done for the whole EEG module until the final design was made. \\

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionof{table}{EEG Module Iterations}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, trim={0.1cm 0 0 0},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={2cm 0 0 1.9cm},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\subsection{Unit Testing for EEG Module}
Following the connections provided from the datasheet, unit testing was done through observing poor signal quality that values to 0. This signified that the device was capturing high-quality EEG signals, and electrodes were correctly positioned with good skin contact.

\begin{figure}[!hpbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{placeholder.pdf}
    \caption{Neurosky TGAM1 Pinouts with Sample Output}
    \label{fig:eegunit2}
\end{figure}

\section{IMU Module}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionof{table}{Iterations for IMU Module}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={0.2cm 0 0 0.5cm},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\subsection{Unit Testing for IMU Module}
Removed Kalman filter; raw gyroscope data was plotted upon testing the IMU module for the x and y-axes.

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={2.0cm 0 0 2.0cm},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\section{CV Module}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionof{table}{Iterations for CV Module}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={0.2cm 0 0 0.2cm},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\subsection{Unit Testing for CV Module (Side-mirror View)}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={1.0cm 0 0 0.5cm},clip]{placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Please never post images of code. No-one wants to retype your code in order to test it.  The width and height of that image seems excessive. Are you sure the image is properly cropped? That is that the extra spacing comes from the image it self. One can normally test this using \fbox{...} around the image. Why are you using your images like this and not via floats?

Most likely your PDF has that padding. You can crop the image using clip, there should be plenty questions on the site showing you how that's done.

@daleif hi, im sorry
it isn't an image but a pdf file. i made a table and converted it into pdf. then tried inserting the pdf.

For LaTeX it is the same thing. The command is called ``\includegraphics` after all.

thank you guys, clip worked!
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight, trim={0 0 0 2.2cm},clip].
didn't know this exist until you guys mentioned it.
very much appreciated :)

Please don't post code fragments. Always make a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

If you are using minipages instead of figures, they won't be able to float and you leave no other option for latex than to place them right there, which will most probably lead to ugly empty spaces and lots of page breaks. Let latex do its job by letting the images float.

Maybe you want to read https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-07#making-images-float

With width=textwidth \centering is redundant.  The one with totalheight shuld instead use \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth} assuming you want it centered vertically on the page.

(1) Do not use width and height together without keepaspectratio except if you want to distort the image. (2) If an image height is \textheight, in the best case only can be placed on a new empty page.  (3) Except in a float (a figure or table) any images bigger that the available space will produce a horrible gap in text since the image cannot move by itself, and then it is up to you make the image smaller to fit in the actual page  or  move  yourself the image to the right place.
